# Where does report rendering in 3-layer architecture belong?

Tags: architecture, report, rendering, layer

I am currently up to a new softwares architecture and I am currently facing a problem: Where does  report rendering belong in a layered architecture?

In my current approach I settled the rendering of my visuals and tables in the presentation layer (whereas the abstraction of the visuals and tables is settled in the business logic layer). Based on those tables and visuals I will generate reports, hence I settled the rendering of the reports in the presentation layer. The reports abstraction is, however, settled in the business logic layer.

Do these architectural choices make any sense? I assume rendering of visuals and tables to be part of the presentation layer, is this correct? What other options are available?

Comment: presentation layer is responsible for rendering so no doubt that the rendering of visuals belongs there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my major concern is the rendering of reports. Since the rendering is tightly coupled to the format the reports are saved to I am beginning to think that this would rather be settled in the data access layer.